# AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'GenericMeta'

Tags: python, flask, typing

I built my api with `flask, connexion and swagger UI`. I defined my apispec with openapi. I created swagger python server stub from swagger editor where you can find [sample project on github](https://github.com/michaelawyu/api_tutorial/tree/master/openapi/photo_album/codegen_server/openapi_server). when I deseialize request JSON data for validation, `util.py` will be used, but I have following error:

**erorr**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\decorators\decorator.py", line 48, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\decorators\security.py", line 327, in wrapper
    return function(request)
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\decorators\uri_parsing.py", line 144, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\decorators\validation.py", line 184, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\connexion\decorators\parameter.py", line 121, in wrapper
    return function(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kim\codegen_server\openapi_server\controllers\default_controller.py", line 74, in immunomatch_ed_post
    body = ImmunomatchEdInput.from_dict(connexion.request.get_json())  # noqa: E501
  File "C:\Users\kim\codegen_server\openapi_server\models\immunomatch_ed_input.py", line 62, in from_dict
    return util.deserialize_model(dikt, cls)
  File "C:\Users\kim\codegen_server\openapi_server\util.py", line 111, in deserialize_model
    setattr(instance, attr, _deserialize(value, attr_type))
  File "C:\Users\kim\codegen_server\openapi_server\util.py", line 26, in _deserialize
    elif type(klass) == typing.GenericMeta:
AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'GenericMeta'
```

error message said `typing` module has no attribute 'GenericMeta', which I don't understand why. can anyone point me out why this error happened? Is that because of `typing` module version error or what? any possible thought to get rid of this error? any thought? thanks

**update: code that I tried**:

```
import six
import typing


def _deserialize(data, klass):
    """Deserializes dict, list, str into an object.

    :param data: dict, list or str.
    :param klass: class literal, or string of class name.

    :return: object.
    """
    if data is None:
        return None

    if klass in six.integer_types or klass in (float, str, bool):
        return _deserialize_primitive(data, klass)
    elif klass == object:
        return _deserialize_object(data)
    elif klass == datetime.date:
        return deserialize_date(data)
    elif klass == datetime.datetime:
        return deserialize_datetime(data)
    elif type(klass) == typing.GenericMeta:
        if klass.__extra__ == list:
            return _deserialize_list(data, klass.__args__[0])
        if klass.__extra__ == dict:
            return _deserialize_dict(data, klass.__args__[1])
    else:
        return deserialize_model(data, klass)
```

error said this line `elif type(klass) == typing.GenericMeta:` is not passed. any idea?

Comment: Please post the code from where this error is getting generated.

Comment: Since Python 3.7 GenericMeta is no longer available. See this issue: https://github.com/pawamoy/mkdocstrings/issues/2 and workaround: https://github.com/pawamoy/mkdocstrings/commit/febf2b9749d97cce80f5d20339372842fdffc908

Comment: @ngShravil.py I pasted the code that I tried. do you have any possible thoughts how to get over with it? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you might change your code to something like this:

```
elif hasattr(klass, '__origin__'):
    if klass.__origin__ == list:
        return _deserialize_list(data, klass.__args__[0])
    if klass.__origin__ == dict:
        return _deserialize_dict(data, klass.__args__[1])
```